# How to use a relative path to link to another local file?

Tags: html

This is a very basic html question, but I can't seem to locate the answer.

I have a local file located here:

```
/Users/Me/Desktop/Main/June/foo.txt
```

In an .html document located within the /Main directory, I can link to the `foo.txt` file using the full path:

```
<a href="file:///Users/Me/Desktop/Main/June/foo.txt">Full Path Link</a>
```

I would like to use relative paths to link to `foo.txt`. Does anyone know how to create a relative path link to this `foo.txt` file?

I tried the code below and a number of similar permutations, but I can't seem to successfully write the relative path link for this local file.

```
<a href="file:///../June/foo.txt">Relative path Link</a>
```

Comment: why don't you just type: <a href="../June/foo.txt">Relative path Link</a>

Comment: The problem with your file:/// is you do not include the hard drive path.  example file:///C:/Users/Me/Desktop/Main/June/foo.txt

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Remove the `file:///` part to have just `../June/foo.txt`.

This should help you out.

Answer (score -1):

If you simply drag your file from the solution explorer into the razor/html page, it will create for you everything you need.