# How do I link to a local file in HTML

Tags: html

I have tried the methods suggested in my book and in the questions in a chat group, but I just get a "File Not Found" error.

These are typical of what I have tried:

`<A HREF="file:///C:/DBAR.txt">Local File</A>`

and

`<A HREF="file://////C:/DBAR.txt">Local File</A>`

I noticed that the Chrome address bar contains the string:

`file:///filepath` to my HTML file. The above address in quotation marks. I assume that the first part of this is my problem, but I do not know why it is there or how to change it, if that is my problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you asking about opening a local html file in your browser ?

Comment: @KeithMcCloy: Could you answer the question posed by Ali Ezzat Odeh? Doing so shows you're engaged.

Comment: Clear now that code-formatting is in place -- just as the question subject says, he wants to link to a local file. The first one _should_ work (it's the correct format for specifying a pathname with a Windows drive letter).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Help with relative path link to local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342854/help-with-relative-path-link-to-local-file)

Comment: First thing to do is Google the question and find dozens of same questions already on *SO*

Comment: Wow, you guys are really quick! I have tried just a filename in the same directory; I have tried the full directory path and the snippet that I have included is a text file in the root directory of C: I have searched on Google and read what I have found. DI am doing something very simple that is wrong, but I cannot see it. Finally the question that I have submitted has been truncated by your system, not by me, and that makes your job really hard. For example in my HTML I look for the file C:/DBAR_Ver.txt, not the filename shown in my original question.

Answer (score 2):

If the file you are trying to open is in the same directory as the page you can use `href="FILENAME"`. If it's not in the same directory you can either put a slash before the "filepath" for example `href="/Desktop/FILENAME"`.

You don't need to write "file:///filepath". just write the directory and that's it.

Comment: I have tried this in Google Chrome;- <H2><A HREF=”C:/DBAR_Ver.txt”>Local File</A> on my computer</H2> but I get back "Your file was not found" and in the search text box of Google Chrome is the string, "file:///C:/Users/krmcc_000/Documents/HTML/"C:/DBAR_Ver.txt" which gives the filepath of my HTML file before the filename that I want (and which is therefore the wrong filepath for the text file that I want to open). From my experience this is a simple and maybe even a stupid problem, but I cannot find what it is.

Comment: Here's a simple fix to your problem. Put your txt file in the same folder or directory as your page. Then simply write href="filename.txt".

Comment: I greatly appreciate all the advice that I have received. I have now tried six different ways to address a local file on my computer, on two different hard drives, using the suggestions given and others, without success. I cannot even see where the problem is, since the HTML below is the main part of this code snippet.

Comment: <P>First try <A HREF=”Secondtry.txt”> first</A>
<P>Try using abs<A HREF=”C:/Users/krmcc_000/Documents/HTML/Secondtry.txt”> second</A>
<P>Second ver absolute<A HREF=”This PC/Documents/HTML/Secondtry.txt”>third</A>
<P>Third ver absolute<A HREF=”file:///C:/Users/krmcc_000/Documents/HTML/Secondtry.txt”> fourth </A>
<P>Try on W:<A HREF=”W:/Documents/Secondtry.txt”> fifth </A>
<P>Again on W:<A HREF=”file:///W:/Documents/Secondtry.txt”> Sixth </A>